# How to download an Azure BLOB Storage file via URL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We've created a folder structure on Azure Storage like below:

```
parentcontainer -> childcontainer -> {pdffiles are uploaded here}
```

We have the URL of the stored `.pdf` files. We don't want to hard code any container name, just download the file using its URL.

Our current attempt at doing this:

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetRootContainerReference();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(pdfFileUrl);

var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
{
    RetryPolicy = new NoRetry()
};

// Read content
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms, null, blobRequestOptions);
    var array = ms.ToArray();
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

But we're getting a "400 Bad Request" here:

```
 blockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms, null, blobRequestOptions);
```

How can we download an Azure BLOB Storage file using only its URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`GetBlockBlobReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference?view=azure-dotnet) takes the filename as an argument in its constructor, not the URL.

In order to download an Azure BLOB Storage item by its URL, you need to instantiate a [`CloudBlockBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-dotnet) yourself using the item's URL:

```
var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(pdfFileUrl), cloudStorageAccount.Credentials);
```

This `blob` can then be downloaded with the code you originally posted.

Comment: Please not that the CloudBlockBlob  is deprecated, you should use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs?view=azure-dotnet instead.