# How to Obtain the URL of an Image Stored in Azure Blob Storage After Upload?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.android

I am building a Xamarin.Android app. This app will allow users to upload images to Azure Blob Storage and access them from any device with an internet connection. I would like to obtain the image URL of the image uploaded, however I don't know how to get the image URL once uploaded. Once I get the image URL I would like to store it in my Azure SQL Database, which is how the app will reference the image required to be downloaded and displayed.

I am currently in the planning phase and researching how to upload images to Azure Blob Storage. I don't know how to obtain the image URL once the image has been uploaded. The image URL will need to be obtained dynamically and cannot be hard-coded.

I have checked this question: [How to download an Azure BLOB Storage file via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726380/how-to-download-an-azure-blob-storage-file-via-url).

The expectation is that users will be able to upload images to Azure Blob Storage, the C# code will obtain the image URL and store this in the database, allowing the app to display the image from its URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL is always

```
https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<blob_name>
```

Note that blob name can also be a path like **2019/02/01/myfile.txt**

Comment: For `<blob_name>` does this mean the image that is uploaded, whatever its file name is will become the file name for the blob?

Comment: If you use code you supply name as parameter during the upload. If you use portal or any tool it will have the same name as on drive.

Comment: @AdamMarczak What if you/someone uploads a file with same name more than once? readme.txt for example.

Comment: is it possible to get the files that exist in a path? e.g. if I want to get all of the files in the 2019/02/01 path?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the portal --> Your Storage account --> blobs (services) --> Click the file

This will open the details of the file.The url can be viewed in Overview .

[image]