# Getting error when Dropbox url copy to azure blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, dropbox

I am using the azure blob storage to copy the dropbox file. But when I try to copy that file via URL, got the 500 error and totalbytes are -1.

I am using StartCopy method of WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob package. But here I get the copyStatus.TotalBytes as -1 and copy not working.

Tried the all types of url as below:

- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1v9re1dozilpdgi/1_32min.mp4?dl=0
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1v9re1dozilpdgi/1_32min.mp4?dl=1
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v9re1dozilpdgi/1_32min.mp4?dl=0

So can you please help me to solve this issue? Anything needs to change in URL or any way to copy the dropbox media to azure blob storage.

Also, I am using the .net 4.8 frameworks with the C#.

Sample Code:

```
string url = "https://dl.dropboxu`enter code here`sercontent.com/s/1v9re1dozilpdgi/1_32min.mp4?dl=0";
            Uri fileUri = new Uri(url);
            string filename = "test-file.mp4";
            var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionstring);
            var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();            
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test-container");
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

            blob.DeleteIfExists();
            blob.StartCopy(fileUri);

            var refBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)container.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(filename);
            var fileLength = refBlob.CopyState.TotalBytes ?? 0;

            while (refBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
            {
                refBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)container.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(filename);
                var copyStatus = refBlob.CopyState;

}
```

**Error message: 500 InternalServerError "Copy failed."**

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written and the detailed error message you’re getting.

Comment: @GauravMantri - Please check the code and error message. I updated the question.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/Dropbox-media-can-t-be-access-by-azure-blob/m-p/575458 ]

Answer (score 0):

We need to use [***`CloudBlockBlob`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet) instead of using [***`GetBlockBlobReference`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet) .

Because the filename, not the URL, is passed to `GetBlockBlobReference` in its Constructor.

For more information please refer the below

[***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726380/how-to-download-an-azure-blob-storage-file-via-url) as suggested by @[***Tobias Tengler***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9456781/tobias-tengler)

& This BLOG:- [***Azure – Upload and Download data using C#.NET***](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/azure-cloud-blob-storage-upload-download-data-file-cloud-net/)